# vb net regex how to match next value

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I am trying to match with RegEx to search all occurence with id number. Here is an example of text I am searching:

```
"[{"name":"Kecantikan","id":"61"},{"name":"Perawatan Wajah","id":"416"},{"name":"Pemutih Wajah","id":"423"
```

this is my pattern : `"id":(?:"\d+")`

and this is my vb net code

```
Dim pattern As String = """id"":""(?>\d+)"""
            For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(newkats, pattern)
                idkat1 = m.Groups(0).Value
                idkat2 = m.Groups(1).Value
                idkat3 = m.Groups(2).Value
            Next
            Label5.Text = idkat1
            Label3.Text = idkat2
            Label11.Text = idkat3
```

it work but only capture first match only . the Label5 Only it show the match,
i also try matchcollection but result still same  .

```
 Dim stringMatches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(newkats, pattern)
            For Each match As Match In stringMatches
                idkat1 = match.Groups(0).Value
                idkat2 = match.Groups(1).Value
                idkat3 = match.Groups(2).Value

            Next
```

How to get the next match like regex101 when using /g global match in vb net ?

Comment: Your `idkatn` vars change each time you assign the new match groups. Concat the values. However, you may use JSON.NET to parse JSON, it is the best you can do here.

Comment: try match[0], match[1], ... edit: match[0].Groups(0).Value, etc

Comment: thank you sir , ya i think better use JSON , i will try wiktor code for json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you have is that you need to add the extracted values to an array or list, else each time you find a match the var value gets re-written.

To parse JSON you'd better use JSON related tools:

```
Dim s As String = "[{""name"":""Kecantikan"",""id"":""61""},{""name"":""Perawatan Wajah"",""id"":""416""},{""name"":""Pemutih Wajah"",""id"":""423""}]"
Dim jss As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim results As New List(Of String)()
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(s)
For Each d In dict
    For Each v In d
       If v.Key = "id" Then
            results.Add(v.Value)
        End If
    Next
Next
results.ForEach(Sub(x) Debug.Print(x))
```

Prints

[image]

Comment: oh yeah this is what i'm looking for ,
thank you sir

Comment: i think i have new problem , sometime i got this exception 
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

and this is my code 
 '
                idkat1 = results(0)
                idkat2 = results(1)
                idkat3 = results(2)'

Comment: You do not check if the item in the list/array exists. Check the length of it first.

Comment: thanks again you made my day , im new btw how to mark this thread as solved ?